# what could be the possible reasons for below stack trace so that i can investigate further?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Environment : AIX 7
Broker :  IIB 9.0.0.8
MQ : 7.5

we get this exception in our environment now and then ( once per week) but its occurring more frequently.
but surprisingly, still Email goes to the recipients.

This is happening with IIB's built-in EmailOutput Node. my assumption is - After submitting the MIME message with an attachment ( part1: body and part2: attachment) by EmailOutput node to Exchange server, probably EmailOutput node is not getting the unique message id as acknowledgement back within given time ( i'm assuming the timeout is indefinite as this is nowhere mentioned in infocenter and also it uses javax mail api as per stacktrace).

I tried all kinds of tracing without any results. Please can i be shared some more pointers that could cause this stack trace so that i could proceed in that direction to test.

```
Caught exception and rethrowing :  <Module Name> Error detected, rethrowing :  <compute node module name>.Main 236.11 PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out1' FINALIZE DEFAULT DELETE DEFAULT; 
Caught exception and rethrowing :  <module name>.Email Output Exception whilst creating MIME message or getting the Message ID :  com.ibm.broker.emailnodes.EmailOutputNode : javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;.  nested exception is:..java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out..at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1462)..at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1376)..at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1215)..at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:586)..at com.ibm.broker.emailnodes.EmailOutputNode.sendMail(EmailOutputNode.java:469)..at com.ibm.broker.emailnodes.EmailOutputNode.sendMimeEmail(EmailOutputNode.java:737)..at com.ibm.broker.emailnodes.EmailOutputNode.sendData(EmailOutputNode.java:378)..at com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbOutputTemplateNode.sendData(MbOutputTemplateNode.java:54).Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out..at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)..at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:165)..at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:134)..at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)..at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:247)..at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:266)..at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:75)..at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1440)..... 7 more. Exception whilst creating MIME message or getting the Message ID :  Exception reading response.Read timed out. : Flow (<Flow name>) Node (Email Output)
</Text>
<Inserts>Exception occured while processing the MQ message:</Inserts>
```

Also, does IIB email Output node has any message size limitations for MIME body and attachment which we need to consider ?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with IBM MQ?

Comment: No but thought its necessary to tell that esb flow reads from MQ and uses MQ queue for backout. :-) and though there's no MQ dependency, apparently majority of the broker functionality relies on MQ like transactionality. i appreciate and respect for coming and have a look if its mq issue :-)

Comment: I see that it says "...while processing the MQ message:", but as you said the error is clearly related to the `EmailOutputNode`, so you should remove the tag from the question.  There are many good IIB people monitoring the [ibm-integration-bus] tag that will see this and likely help.

Comment: You will have to contact your SMTP administrator and understand the restrictions put at its end. Sometimes rules are put in the SMTP server to throttle certain from or to email id's. Payload size also could be one of the restrictions. May be your org's SMTP server is getting overwhelmed with requests. Let us know what you find. Thank You.

Comment: I checked with our SMTP admin and he says there's no such restrictions set on email especially that are sent from servers. he says its just queues up and sends it.also he says there's lot of rules set on server that alerts them if they see some issue.